# Find iOS App Installation Analytics Source

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to capture couple of information.

1. I have an app on Apple/Google Stores.
2. I run a campaign on newspapers/web-sites to install the App (for e.g. QR code in newspaper and ads in Web)

Is there a way where I can
1. Find out which QR code was scanned and from which newspaper?
2. Is this information available via App Store Dev Console ? Or if there is any API ?

regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a QR code, have it link to your website so you can log analytics and then forward to a store. For different papers, use different QR codes with different links / parameters.

Apple app store doesn't offer any information on where users came from. I think Google app store offers some information on where users came from.

Comment: Thanks. The idea to capture via my website seems great.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have installed Google Analytics on you application, then connect Google Play to your Google Analytics account.

After that you should generate link which will be then embeeded into you QR Code:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns?hl=pl#google-play-url-builder

For some more Anlaytics for mobile apps I recommend: http://www.distimo.com/

Regards, Grzegorz